# Can this form validation be simplified made to memory leak free for all browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am doing a validation and I believe that there are many things that can be reduced or removed.  I am still re-working this. But I am looking for some experts to look at my code and offer the very best approach for both individual and form submit error handling.

```
(function(){

    var calledIt = function (event, params) {

        $.each(params, function(i,element) {
           var prop = element.get(0).type;
           var value = null;
           switch(prop) {
            case "text" :
            case "select-one" :
                value = element.val();
            break;
            case "radio" :
            case "checkbox" :
                var name = element.prop('name');
                value = $("input[name='"+name+"']:checked").val();
            break;
           }
           if(!value) {
                element.focus();
                return false;
           }
        })
    }

    $(document).on('focusInitiate', calledIt); // sending to focus on invalid element focus on submit,

})();

var Validator = function (form) {

    this.form = form,
        this.elements = this.form.find(':input:not(button, input[type=submit])'),
        button = this.form.find('input[type=submit]'),
        that = this,
        this.submitIt = false;

    this.form.submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var requiredElement = [];

        if(that.submitIt) {
            console.log('set a model');
        } else {
            console.log('don\'t set a model')
        }

        $.each(this.elements, function(i,element){
            var tagName = String(element.type).toUpperCase();

            switch(tagName) {
                case "TEXT" :
                case "TEXTAREA" :
                case "SELECT-ONE" :
                    that.inputHandler({tagName:tagName,element:$(this)});
                    requiredElement.push($(this));
                break;
                case "RADIO"      :
                case "CHECKBOX"   :
                    that.changeHandler({tagName:tagName,element:$(this)});
                    requiredElement.push($(this))
                break;
            }
            return requiredElement;
        })

        $.when.apply($, requiredElement).done(function(){
            $.event.trigger("focusInitiate", [requiredElement]);
        })
    })

    this.validate = function () {

        $.each(this.elements, function(i,element){

            var tagName = $(element).prop('type').toUpperCase();

            switch(tagName) {
                case "TEXT" :
                case "TEXTAREA" :
                case "SELECT-ONE" :
                    $(element).on('input focusout', {tagName:tagName,element:$(this)}, that.inputHandler);
                break;
                case "RADIO"      :
                case "CHECKBOX"   :
                    $(element).on('change focusout', {tagName:tagName,element:$(this)}, that.changeHandler);
                break;
            }

        });

    }


    this.handleElements = function (params,status) {

        var tagName = params.data ? params.data.tagName : params.tagName;
        var element = params.data ? params.data.element : params.element;

        if(status==="inputHandler") {
            var value = params.data ? params.data.element.val() : params.element.val();
            return {"tagName" :tagName,"element" : element, 'value' : value };
        }

        if(status==="changeHandler") {
            var name =   element.prop('name');
            var value = $("input[name='"+name+"']:checked").val()
            return {"tagName" :tagName,"element" : element, 'value' : value };
        }

    }

    this.inputHandler = function (params) {
        var processedParams = that.handleElements(params,"inputHandler");
        that.errorHandler(processedParams);
    }

    this.changeHandler = function (params) {
        var processedParams = that.handleElements(params,"changeHandler");
        that.errorHandler(processedParams);
    }

    this.errorHandler = function (params) {
        var actualValue = $.trim(params.value),
            tagName = params.tagName,
            target = params.element;


        switch(tagName) {

            case 'TEXT' :                
                if(!actualValue) {
                    $(target).next('.error').css('display','block');
                    that.submitIt = false;
                } else {
                    $(target).next('.error').css('display','none');
                    that.submitIt = true;
                }
                break;
            case "SELECT-ONE" : 
                if(actualValue === 'Select') {
                    $(target).next('.error').css('display','block');
                    that.submitIt = false;
                } else {
                    $(target).next('.error').css('display','none');
                    submitIt = true
                }
                break;
           case "RADIO" : 
           case "CHECKBOX" : 
                if(actualValue && actualValue !== 'undefined'){
                    $(target).siblings('.error').css('display','none');
                    that.submitIt = true;
                } else {
                    $(target).siblings('.error').css('display','block');
                    that.submitIt = false;
                }
                break;
        }

        return that.submitIt;
    }

}

var initiateValidate = function () {
    var form = $('form');
    form.find('*').off();
    var validator = new Validator(form);
    validator.validate();
}

initiateValidate();
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3gwebtrain/68kv5/27/)

Comment: In your title you mention memory-leak but not in the text of your question, are you sure there is such a problem ?

Comment: I did not find any problem. I am looking the feedback like you kind of people. with simplification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The design problems in this code bother me a lot more than the code problems.

- Every single input type is mandatory, that seems not very useful, you should have a class or something other to identify which fields are mandatory
- Your text input fields dont have the `id` attribute set
- You are using `span` for labels instead of the [label tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label).
- You predefine 1 single error per field, what if you need 2 validations with a different message

From a once over on the coding

- `var value = null`; -> KISS -> `var value;`
- `var prop = element.get(0).type;` <- Why `prop`, why not `type`?
- This:

  ```
  $(target).next('.error').css('display','none');
  submitIt = true
  ```

  is copy pasted a ton of times, refactor this
- This switch: `switch(tagName) {` is copy pasted a ton of times as well -> refactor

I think this needs some serious rethinking on your end.